# Django 1.0, using default password reset

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use the password reset setup that comes with Django, but the documentation is not very good for it.  I'm using Django 1.0 and I keep getting this error:

```
Caught an exception while rendering: Reverse for 'mysite.django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments ...
```

in my urlconf I have something like this:

```
#django.contrib.auth.views
urlpatterns = patterns('django.contrib.auth.views',    
    (r'^password_reset/$', 'password_reset', {'template_name': 'accounts/registration/password_reset_form.html', 'email_template_name':'accounts/registration/password_reset_email.html', 'post_reset_redirect':'accounts/login/'}),
    (r'^password_reset/done/$', 'password_reset_done', {'template_name': 'accounts/registration/password_reset_done.html'}),
    (r'^reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', 'password_reset_confirm', {'template_name': 'accounts/registration/password_reset_confirm.html', 'post_reset_redirect':'accounts/login/', 'post_reset_redirect':'accounts/reset/done/'}),
    (r'^reset/done/$', 'password_reset_complete', {'template_name': 'accounts/registration/password_reset_complete.html'}),
)
```

The problem seems to be in this file:

```
password_reset_email.html
```

on line 7

```
{% url django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm uidb36=uid, token=token %}
```

I'm at loss as to what's going on, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wanted to post the solution I came up with.  The problem was in this line:

```
{% url django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm uidb36=uid, token=token %}
```

I'm not really a 100% why either, so I just hard coded the url like this:

```
http://mysite.com/accounts/reset/{{uid}}-{{token}}/
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: I used your example, and had to change to not use keyword parameters.

```
{% url django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm uid, token %}
```

Named parameters do work, as long as both uid and token are defined.  If either are not defined or blank I get the same error you do:

```
{% url django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm uidb36=uid, token=token %}
```

Comment: Can you explain this a little more.  What do you mean by "Try adding a line for password_reset_confirm in urls.py".  The third URL in my above example is for password_reset_confirm.  How else should I be adding it to my urls.py file?

Thanks

Comment: My mistake in overlooking that, I edited what worked for me above.

Answer (score 2):

I've struggled with this for over an hour trying everything on this page and every other page on the internet. Finally to solve the problem in my case i had to delete

```
{% load url from future %}
```

from the top of my password_reset_email.html template.

Also note, "uidb36=uid" in the url script. Here's my full password_reset_email.html template, I hope it saves someone some time:

```
{% autoescape off %}
    You're receiving this e-mail because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{ site_name }}.


Please go to the following page and choose a new password:
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm uidb36=uid token=token %}
{% endblock %}

Your username, in case you've forgotten:" %} {{ user.username }}

Thanks for using our site!

The {{ site_name }} team

{% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I figured out myself not 10 minutes ago. The solution is to add the post_change_redirect value to the dictionary of arguments you are passing to the password_reset view.

So this is what mine now look like:

```
(r'^/password/$', password_change, {'template_name': 'testing/password.html', 'post_change_redirect': '/account/'})
```

I hope that does it for you! I agree that the documentation for this particular feature is lacking somewhat, but this solved the exact same issue for my project.

Edit: I really should have scrolled across - you've included that already. Apologies for that, but I hope you get it sorted :)